# Typerror using class in Python

Tags: python, class, object

I am learning about classes and objects in Python, but when I run this code the output is an error. Can anyone show me how to fix it?

```
class Person :
def _init_ (self,name,age) :
    self.name = name
    self.age = age


def myfunction(self) :
        print("Hello My Name Is" + self.name)

 p1 = Person("John",36)
 p1.myfunction()
```

Here's the error output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\IPB\PENUGASAN\SEMESTER
> 2\STRAKDAT\Penugasan\Pertemuan 3\Materi 3.py", line 16, in 
> p1 = Person("John",36) TypeError: Person() takes no arguments
>
> ------------------ (program exited with code: 1)
>
> Press any key to continue . . . Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

Comment: `__init__` not `_init_` (you need double underscores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:
Your indentation is not set properly.
The `__init__` should be with double underscores.

Try this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age) :
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


    def myfunction(self) :
        print("Hello My Name Is " + self.name)


p1 = Person("John",36)
p1.myfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `_init_` function in your class is not the main initializer. To make it that, rename it to `__init__`.